# DHL - how to integrate the DHL plugin and hide the rate

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping-methods, dhl

i’m currently struggling to get the DHL not to pull the quote and show on the checkout as these quotes get added to the Subtotal of the order and since the store offers International free shipping .
So the store is sending the order request to DHL and the response comes with a quote/rates, is there a way to not get the rates from DHL, please see screenshot below from the checkout which shows the DHL rate and would like to be free of charge

[image]

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do that in Magento. There are third-party apps that can surface the DHL shipping option and put in custom rules for shipping rates. Zonos does this, but most merchants that get install it use it for the duty and tax calculation, even though it does custom shipping rates as well.

https://marketplace.magento.com/zonos-dutytax.html